# How to create new container group in azure vnet using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-container-instances, vnet

I need to create Azure container group with 1 container instance which will be integrated in a specific Vnet using python. But I didn't find anything useful, can anyone help me ?

Comment: You can try using the [`begin_create_or_update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-containerinstance/azure.mgmt.containerinstance.operations.containergroupsoperations?view=azure-python#begin-create-or-update-resource-group-name--container-group-name--container-group----kwargs-) method under the `ContainerGroupsOperations` Class in the  `azure.mgmt.containerinstance.operations` module of Azure python SDK

Comment: Please check the [`ContainerGroup` Class Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-containerinstance/azure.mgmt.containerinstance.models.containergroup?view=azure-python) for more information. The parameter `subnet_ids` of the `ContainerGroup` object defines the subnet resource IDs for a container group. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-containerinstance/azure.mgmt.containerinstance.models.containergroupsubnetid?view=azure-python

Comment: @Srijit_Bose-MSFT I am new in azure, what is the id in ContainerGroupSubnetId constructor ? where do i find it exactly

Comment: Every resource in Azure has a unique resource ID in the format like `/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/{Resource-Group-Name}/providers/{ResourceProvider}/{ResourceType}/{ResourceName}`. If you want to deploy the Azure Container Instance in an existing Azure Virtual network subnet then you must provide the subnet's resource ID which should look similar to `/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VnetName/subnets/SubnetName`

Comment: For e.g., the following [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/what-is-azure-cli) command returns the resource ID of a subnet `test` in the `test-net` virtual network located in `test-rg` resource group: `az network vnet subnet show -g test-rg --vnet-name test-net -n test --query id -o tsv`

Comment: You can use the [get](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.operations.subnetsoperations?view=azure-python#get-resource-group-name--virtual-network-name--subnet-name--expand-none----kwargs-) method in `SubnetsOperations` Class of `azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.operations` module of the Azure Python SDK to return an object of type [Subnet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models.subnet?view=azure-python). `$result.id` will give you the resource ID of the desired subnet.

Comment: I couldnt import 'ContainerGroupSubnetId' from azure.mgmt.containerinstance.models to try your suggestion. :/

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT yes I know I just still have errors so I cannot say if this is really the solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the delegated subnet to be used by container group using the below code :

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
credential = AzureCliCredential()
subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-e00a844e059b"
#credential = DefaultAzureCredential
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)
resource_group_name = "ansumantest"
location = "West US 2"
virtual_network_name = "ansuman-vnet"
subnet_name = "acisubnet"
Subnet=network_client.subnets.get(resource_group_name, virtual_network_name, subnet_name)
print(Subnet.id)
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can add something similar as given below as per your requirement to the above code provided to get the subnetid:

```
from azure.mgmt.containerinstance import ContainerInstanceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.containerinstance.models import (ContainerGroup,
                                                 Container,
                                                 ContainerGroupNetworkProtocol,
                                                 ImageRegistryCredential,
                                                 ContainerPort,
                                                 IpAddress,
                                                 Port,
                                                 ResourceRequests,
                                                 ResourceRequirements,
                                                 ContainerGroupSubnetId,
                                                 OperatingSystemTypes)
    subnet_id = Subnet.id
    container_client = ContainerInstanceManagementClient(credential,subscription_id)
    container_image_name = "your private image present in acr "
    user_name = "username for the server"
    password= "password for the server"
    # Configure the container
    container_resource_requests = ResourceRequests(memory_in_gb=1, cpu=1.0)
    container_resource_requirements = ResourceRequirements(requests=container_resource_requests)
    container = Container(name=container_group_name,image=container_image_name,resources=container_resource_requirements,ports=[ContainerPort(port=80)])
    # Configure the container group
    ports = [Port(protocol=ContainerGroupNetworkProtocol.tcp, port=80)]
    group_ip_address = IpAddress(ports=ports,type="Private")
    acisubnet = ContainerGroupSubnetId(id=subnet_id,name=subnet_name)
    imagecredentials= ImageRegistryCredential(server="server.azurecr.io",username=user_name,password=password)
    container_group= ContainerGroup(location=location,containers=[container], os_type=OperatingSystemTypes.WINDOWS,ip_address=group_ip_address,subnet_ids=[acisubnet],image_registry_credentials=imagecredentials)
    # Create the container group
    container_client.container_groups.begin_create_or_update(resource_group_name,container_group_name,container_group)
```

> **Note:**
>
> - If you are creating a container group in your vnet then you won't be able to have public access anymore for the container group
>   and you can't use a public image (error below) . You have to only use
>   your private image present on your Azure container registry.
>
>   [image]
> - If you are not sure about subnet delegation then please go to your
>   `vnet>>subnet>>click on subnet to be used by containerGroup>>select the subnet delegation as show in image>>save`
>
>   [image]

Comment: the subnets.get have been given me this error:  HttpResponseError: (InvalidApiVersionParameter) The api-version '2021-02-01' is invalid. The supported versions are '2021-04-01,2021-01-01,2020-10-01,2020-09-01,2020-08-01,2020-07-01,2020-06-01,2020-05-01,2020-01-01,2019-11-01,2019-10-01,2019-09-01,2019-08-01,2019-07-01,2019-06-01,2019-05-10,2019-05-01,2019-03-01,2018-11-01,2018-09-01,2018-08-...

Comment: @Houdakilani,can you try reinstalling the network module and then try the code .

Comment: The same, can you please share the versions you are using with pip freeze ?

Comment: Hello @Houdakilani , I am using the following versions of the models as shown in ![image](https://i.imgur.com/5QyRZDs.png)